# open SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have button that call async method I want at the callback of this method to open SaveFileDialog, I know it will raise security exception

but any work around, I depend on the callback in knowing the paramerters will be used at the save dialog

for example I call webservice to check if the file exists or not

if exist and word version I will set the property of the savefiledilaoge to word and so on

calling webservice for check is async so in callback I get all the information I want to know

Comment: What code do you have.. What is your exact question...??

Comment: Please show the code you have .. we are not mind readers here..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a framework like MVVM Light, you can send a message from your callback to your UI thread (passing your parameters required for saving).

EDIT. Adding example

In your code behind page most likely, you will need to setup a listener for the custom message we will send. Its good practice to do this in your onload or onnavigateto methods. I'll assume that your callback will load up a custom object called `CustomObjectWithParams` that you are getting from db.

In your xaml code behind:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // the "MyViewModel.OpenSaveDialogRequest" can be any string.. it just needs to synch up with what was sent from the viewmodel below
        Messenger.Default.Register<CustomObjectWithParams>(this, "MyViewModel.OpenSaveDialogRequest", objParams => ShowSaveDialog(objParams));
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    private void ShowSaveDialog(CustomObjectWithParams obj) {
        // do your  open save here in the UI thread
    }

    // be smart, make sure you unregister this listener when you navigate away!
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        Messenger.Default.Unregister<CustomObjectWithParams>(this);
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }
```

Now in your view model callback function (not running on UI thread right)... you want to send the params you are getting asynch. You can do this as so:

```
protected void your_asynch_callbackfunction(your args) {
            CustomObjectWithParams objParams = new CustomObjectWithParams();
            // fill up this object here....

            // now send the object to the UI to do something with it
            Messenger.Default.Send<CustomObjectWithParams>(objParams, "MyViewModel.OpenSaveDialogRequest");

        }
```

Comment: yes I use it how to do that please

Comment: thanks a lot ,by I work in viewmodel that not interact directly with view code behind

Comment: the viewmodel am on it for retirieveing data to grid , and I have button when click on it should start save provcess

Comment: it would not be good practice to call a dialog from your view model. That violates separation of concerns. I would expect that there is some view related to this no?

Comment: Example: Button calls ViewModel.StartSave(). Then the ViewModel.SaveComplete() finishes. In SaveComplete(), send the message using example above. In the view that contains your button, add code above to listen for message.

Comment: the viewmodel, contain the record of the grid ,

Comment: im really struggling picturing your scenario w/o code. ive tried to outline the basic architectural approach you will need to use. You may need to step back and lay things out a bit differently

Comment: ok I got it I did everything , but still give security error

Answer (score 0):

Messing around with this I have tried this in a small test project , 
perhaps you are wanting to do something like this..
Since you refuse to post relevant code, make others as well as myself rely on our 
mind reading skills

```
public class AsyncSaveTester : 'put yourclassIheritance Here'
{
    private SaveFileDialog asyncSaveDialog;

    public SaveFileDialog AsyncSaveDialog
    {
        get { return asyncSaveDialog; }
        set { asyncSaveDialog = value; }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        asyncSaveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        //Write your code to Show the Dialog here
    }

    // where is the handler for your webservice call...find that and call the Save method from there
    private void Save(string fileToSave)
    {
        Stream fileStream = asyncSaveDialog.OpenFile();
        // If you choose to use Streaming, then you would write the code here to do the file Streaming from 
        // the web Service call
    }
}
```